# Google Apps Engine, Sending out Emails Receiving this Error (Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission.) Java

Tags: java

I've figured out how to receive emails via Google Engine.  Now I'm trying to send out a confirmation that the email was received, but I keep getting this error:

```
com.jkimgroup.emailtospreadsheet.MailHandlerServlet doPost:
  MessagingException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: 
  Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: 
  Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25 (java.net.SocketException: Permission denied:
  Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission.))
```

I have the "from" address set to my admin email.  Is this an error message where perhaps I'm not including the correct jar files in the /WEB-INF/lib folder?

And I used google's standard example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    // ...
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    String msgBody = "...";

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                         new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "Mr. User"));
        msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
        msg.setText(msgBody);
        Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // ...
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I'm starting to think perhaps I'm suppossed to use the appengine librares instead for mail processing even though the official documentation is pointing toward using JavaMail 1.4.7?

In case that's the case, here are the libraries I've imported in my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//Am I supossed to import this one instead of the javax.mail.* jars?
//import com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailService.Message;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
```

**UPDATE 2 FIXED NOW**
I added in Oracle's JavaMail JARs to my app which did cause the problems according to:

> All of the JavaMail classes you need are included with the App Engine
>   SDK. Do not add Oracle®'s JavaMail JARs to your app; if you do, the
>   app will throw exceptions.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/?csw=1

Comment: What's DFP?   Are you referring to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dfp-java/    

I'm using Eclipse as my program / compiler, but I'm not familiar with DFP.

Comment: Yes I am referring to that.  I asked because Google search results showed hits for *"Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission"* in conjunction with DFP.

Comment: LOL.  I just did this search, and it circled back to this post: https://www.google.com/search?q=Permission+denied%3A+Attempt+to+access+a+blocked+recipient+without+permission.&oq=Permission+denied%3A+Attempt+to+access+a+blocked+recipient+without+permission.&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i62.175j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6647ee0f0431b9e2&q=google+apps+engine+Permission+denied:+Attempt+to+access+a+blocked+recipient+without+permission.&safe=off

Comment: @StephenC  I don't think they're related (or I could be wrong).  "As of v201302, this library has been deprecated. Use new library with more features."  It looks to be more about ads rather than emails?  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer ...

The exception message says this:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25 
        (java.net.SocketException: Permission denied:
         Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission.))
```

So the transport is attempting to use an SMTP service running on the same machine as the GAE.  But the error message seems to indicate that it succeeding in connecting, and the SMTP service refused to accept the email for delivery to any of the recipients.

So I would suggest that you do the following:

- Try it out with a real email addresses not "xxx@example.com" addresses.
- Check the configurations for your local MTA service (whatever it is) to see if it is configured to relay email to external addresses.
- Check the MTA log files.  There should be some record of the email rejection.

Comment: Yeah, I substituted in my actual code to be what my actual admin email is.

Comment: I'm using Google Apps Engine.  I'm not sure what you're referring to regarding the MTA service.  I thought Google Apps Engine is supposed to streamline all of that for me.

Comment: MTA == Mail Transfer Agent; i.e. the sendmail/postfix/qmail/exim/whatever daemon running on 127.0.0.1 / port 25.  Apparently it is being used here ... or so the error message says.